# Material 3 Android - dark theme uses shadows instead of lighter color elevations. Has anyone experienced this? How to solve a problem?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

MaterialComponents works correctly and uses elevationOverlayColor.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNs8V.png)
But Material3...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OJ05.png)
night-theme:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.HiNote" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/secondaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/secondaryTextColor</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/white</item>
    <item name="elevationOverlayColor">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/backGroundDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hintTextColor</item>

</style>

<style name="Theme.HiNote.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.HiNote.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="Theme.HiNote.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.Dark" />
```

card:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/note_card"
    style="?attr/materialCardViewElevatedStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/backgroundColor"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/note_timestamp">
```

And the appbar is affected so I can't solve this problem for very long. Maybe there is some type of elevation so that it can be set?
Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After implementing [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/apply-dynamic-color#0) point by point, I achieved the desired result.